# SQL Query work from Oracle SQL Developer but not from code

Tags: c#, oracle

i have the following SQL query that works fine when i run it from Oracle's SQL developer tool:

```
SELECT inn.TABLE_NAME, inn.COLUMN_NAME, inn.data_scale, inn.data_length, 
inn.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
FROM
(SELECT t.TABLE_NAME,  c.COLUMN_NAME, c.data_scale, c.data_length, 
cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY 
cons.CONSTRAINT_TYPE desc) num
 from user_tables t join user_tab_cols c on c.table_name = t.table_name
left join all_cons_columns cols on cols.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME and 
cols.COLUMN_NAME = c.COLUMN_NAME
left join all_constraints cons on cons.constraint_name = 
cols.constraint_name
WHERE t.tablespace_name = 'name') inn
WHERE inn.num=1
order by inn.TABLE_NAME, inn.COLUMN_NAME asc;
```

But when I run it in the code I get error:
"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Any Idea?

Thanks for advance.

[Edit]
OK, this is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = Utilities.renderMethodFunc(command, commandParameters);
using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{...}
```

and you can see in the picture the value of command - it's exactly like what I wrote.
[command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwmAb.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the C# code you are using to run this query.  The error is almost certainly in how you are constructing the query in a C# string literal.

Comment: "in the code"? **What** code? You have problem in your code, but you don't post it. The query works OK from SQL Developer, so the error is NOT in the SQL code. And yet that's the ONLY code you show? How do you expect to get help?

Comment: have you noticed the 'quotation marks' around sql, or semicolumn(;) at the end of sql in your code?

Comment: @user2992143: Please edit your question and add your erroneous C# code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it.
The problem was the ';' at the end...